# Resign keyboard if user touches UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiview, ios4, uiimageview

**Problem**

I have a xib file with a UIImageView over the top of the background. I have it setup to resign when the user touches the background, but i cant figure out how to get the keyboard to resign if the user touches the UIImageView.

**Question**

What could I use to have the keyboard resign if they touch either the UIImageView OR the background?

**Setup**

There is an event set to listen for touch down on background that calls this method

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender{
[userPassword resignFirstResponder];
[userLogin resignFirstResponder];    
}
```

that works beautifully, but i'm not sure how to link up the UIImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure user interaction is disabled for the `UIImageView`. Then touches on that element should be passed along to the underlying view. This effectively ignores taps on the image view entirely.

Alternatively, if you want to capture taps on the image view for some other reason you could create a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for the `UIImageView` whose action is your `backgroundTap` method or some other method. (You might have to create a different method with an appropriate signature for use with the gesture recognizer, but your method above may be just fine.)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Im sure all the code below would have worked but this is definitely the easiest. Im sure i will run into a situation where the check on user interaction wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture  =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTap:)];
[tapGesture setDelegate:self];        
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a tap gesture to the view.

In your .h:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap;    

}

@property (nonatomic, strong /*if using ARC, if not then use retain*/) UITapGestureRecognizer *tap;

-(void) dismissKeyboard;
```

Then in your .m:

```
@synthesize tap;

//in your viewDidLoad
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
tap.delegate = self;

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:self.view.window];

}

-(void) dismissKeyboard {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
if ([yourImageView isFirstResponder]) {
[yourImageView resignFirstResponder];
}
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

}
```

That's how I did it.